# Problem populating a vector with constructed struct objects

Tags: c++, vector, struct, constructor, initializer-list

I'm implementing my version of the dining philosophers problem using `ncurses` and encountered a problem initializing a vector of `Fork` objects.

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <ncurses.h>

...

struct Fork
{
    Fork(WINDOW *fork_window) : fork_window(fork_window) {}
    std::mutex m;
    WINDOW *fork_window;
};

std::vector<WINDOW *> fork_windows; // properly populated later
std::vector<Fork> forks;

...

for (int i = 0; i < num_of_phils; i++)
{
    forks.emplace_back(Fork(fork_windows[i]));
}
```

I wonder what my mistake here is (I'm not that experienced in modern C++). Is the initializer list in `Fork` wrong or an `std::mutex` member causes a problem? I successfully populated another vector in a similar fashion but the other struct had no `std::mutex` member, only `WINDOW *` and three `ints`.

The error in the terminal is quite long and says:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Fork::Fork(Fork&&)’, 

...

note: ‘Fork::Fork(Fork&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
```

This is the first time I see such an error and googling it also didn't help as I didn't find a similar case anywhere.

Comment: You are trying to `emplace` and object in a `vector` which requires a move constructor, but you don't have one, thus you get `error: use of deleted function ‘Fork::Fork(Fork&&)’`. Solution: create a move constructor

Comment: @nick `std::mutex` is not moveable, so creating a move constructor is not possible with `Fork` defined as-is.

Comment: @PaulSanders assuming he wants to move the `mutex` which he never claimed he wanted to. If the `mutex` is for some internal thing (such as multiple threads messing with the `Window*`), getting a new `mutex` is fine.

Comment: If the `mutex` is for some external thing, it really begs the question why isn't it global when it really should be.

Comment: @nick Look at the declaration of `Fork`.  The mutex is a member variable, and that cannot be moved or copied, hence the error message the OP is seeing.  Sure, `Fork` can be redesigned to be copyable / moveable but that complicates things since now you *do* have to provide your own move / copy  constructors and assignment operators.  Better - simpler certainly -  to do as I suggest below.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm not saying your solution is wrong or bad, I'm just saying that there is nothing in his question that suggests he actually _needs_ to move that `mutex`. Which means that implementing a move constructor will get rid of that error. Sure, there are best practices such as the rule of 5 in this situation, but that only adds two functions, one of which he probably needs anyway (destructor), and he may have posted a _minimal_ example where that was removed for simplicity.

Comment: @nick I guess changing the `std::mutex` in `Fork` to a `std::unique_ptr <std::mutex>` would be an easy fix, but with the class as defined it's not possible to write a move constructor.

Comment: @PaulSanders of course it is: `Fork(Fork&& f){ fork_window = f.fork_window; f.fork_window = nullptr; }` this moves the fork window ptr over, nulls the other one, and constructs a new `mutex` for the new object. The same works for the copy operator, but this looks like the sort of class that shouldn't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

As things stand, you cannot have a `std::vector<Fork>` because `std::mutex` is neither copyable nor movable and this implicitly deletes both the copy and move constructors of `Fork`.

Consider instead using a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fork>>`, like this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <ncurses.h>

...

struct Fork
{
    Fork(WINDOW *fork_window) : fork_window(fork_window) {}
    std::mutex m;
    WINDOW *fork_window;
};

std::vector<WINDOW *> fork_windows; // properly populated later
std::vector<std::unique_ptr <Fork>> forks;

...

for (int i = 0; i < num_of_phils; i++)
{
    forks.emplace_back(new Fork(fork_windows[i]));
}
```

If you prefer, you can replace:

```
forks.emplace_back (new Fork (fork_windows [i]));
```

with:

```
forks.push_back (std::make_unique <Fork> (fork_windows [i]));
```

It's largely a matter of style.

---

**Edit:**

An alternative way of fixing your code is to declare `Fork` like this:

```
struct Fork
{
    Fork(WINDOW *fork_window) : fork_window(fork_window) {}
    std::unique_ptr <std::mutex> m = std::make_unique <std::mutex> ();
    WINDOW *fork_window;
};
```

Now `Fork` is moveable (but not copyable).